# Converter for list of objects that have as unique id a tuple of 2 member variables

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, converters

I am trying to map a `list of objects` into a `<p:selectOneMenu` (code shown below):

**Attribute.java**

```
public class Attribute implements Serializable {
 private String name;
 private String type;
 private String value; //getters setters constructors ommitted

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Attribute attribute = (Attribute) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, attribute.name) &&
            Objects.equals(type, attribute.type);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, type, value);
}
```

**p:selectOneMenu code**

```
 <p:selectOneMenu label="Existing Attributes" value="#{cellBean.selectedAttributeFromExistings}"
                                                 converter="attrConverter">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Existing attribute" itemValue="#{null}" itemDisabled="true"/>
      <f:selectItems value="#{cellBean.allAttributes}" var="attr" itemLabel="#{attr.name}" itemValue="#{attr}"/>
  <p:ajax event="change" update="@form" process="@form"/>
  </p:selectOneMenu>
```

**Attribute converter (attrConverter) code**

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Attribute.class,  value = "attrConverter")
public class AttributeConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
    String type = s.substring(s.indexOf(":") + 2, s.indexOf(","));
    String name = s.substring(s.indexOf("name: ") + 6 , s.length());
    Attribute attribute = new Attribute(type, name);
    return attribute;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object attr) {
    if(attr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else{
        Attribute attribute = new Attribute();
        String s = "";
        Iterator iterator = ((LinkedTreeMap)attr).keySet().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            String value = (String) ((LinkedTreeMap)attr).get(key);
            if(key.equals("name")){
                attribute.setName(value);
            }
            else if(key.equals("type")){
                attribute.setType(value);
            }

        }
        return attribute.toString();
    }
}
```

However, when I am selecting a value from the dropdown menu I am getting the following exception

> Validation Error: Value is not valid : Validation Error: Value is not valid

[image: error message]

followed by an error message / pop on the top right of my screen, any idea what I am doing wrong?

**PS:**  I have seen lots of examples that they use a `unique id` in order to retrieve the object through a DTO in the `getAsObject` method, in my example the `uniqueness` of the the `Attribute` object is the combination of `type && value` member variables.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: So you are saying it works with a plain jsf `h:selectOneMenu`? (And and converters are a JSF thing, not a PrimeFaces thing.

Comment: And in the `getAsString` your attr object is a `LinkedTreeMap` while the `getAsObject` returns an `Attribute`.... That is inconsistent and effectively wrong.

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje thanks for the comment, indeed the fact that in the `getAsString` the attr object was a LinkedTreeMap while the `getAsObject` returns an `Attribute` was an incosistency (and the problem). The fault was that I accidentaly serialized wrongly a json using `gson` and instead of a List of attributes it converted it into LinkedTreeMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you cast attr to `LinkedTreeMap`, you need to cast it to `Attribute` class. So your converter class should be:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Attribute.class,  value = "attrConverter")
public class AttributeConverter implements Converter {

 @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0 && !value.isEmpty()) {
         /*I take your bean as ViewScoped */
            CellBean cellBean = (CellBean) context.getViewRoot().getViewMap().get("cellBean");
            for(Attribute a : cellBean.getAllAttributes()){
                String combined = a.getType()+a.getValue();
                if(combined.equals(value)){
                    return a;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)            {
        if (value != null) {
            Attribute a = (Attribute) value;
            return a.getType()+a.getValue();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Asker oriented:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
    String[] typeAndName = s.split("#");
    return new Attribute(typeAndName[0], typeAndName[1]);

}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object attr) {
    if(attr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else{
        /* I assume your type and name don't contain '#' charachter */
        return ((Attribute)attr).getType()+"#"+((Attribute)attr).getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right @mismanc, I accidentally serialized wrong the List of Attributes into LinkedTreeMap, that was the root of the problem, I will post the final answer which is similar to yours... +1 :)

Comment: I don't know why you create new object in every call of getAsObject function, but I will give you simple way to decode type and name. it is up to you use or not check the update ;).. @NickAth

Comment: I like your way of decoding, unfortunately I am facing a new problem when I am trying to submit the form that the `selectOneMenu` belongs now, (javascript error) which is caused I guess because of the converter since when i delete the `selectOneMenu` from the form the submit takes place `VM2072:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Object.jsf.util.chain (jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:3192)` 


I can attach a screenshot of the error if you wish :)

Comment: For new problem you must open new question @NickAth.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem was wrong serialization from my side using `gson`, I converted the `Attribute` object into `LinkedTreeMap` which is an incosistency as mentioned in the comments section too. When I made the serialization correctly the `getAsObject` and the `getAsString` functions had the following form:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
    String type = s.substring(s.indexOf("type=") + 5, s.indexOf(" "));
    String name = s.substring(s.indexOf("name=") + 5 , s.length());
    Attribute attribute = new Attribute(type, name);
    return attribute;

}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object attr) {
    if(attr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return "type="+((Attribute)attr).getType()+" name="+((Attribute)attr).getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the real cause was not the wrong serialization but what was in my comment and the other answer that you had two different types. That **that** was caused by a wrong serialization is sort of irrelevant ;-)

Comment: You are right, I repeated in my posted answer the real cause was what you mentioned (type incosistency) :)